# first element after the clicked element

Tags: jquery, dom

How do I get the `first` element which has an specific class, right after the *clicked* element.

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box-data"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box-data"></div>
```

Here is my not-working solution:

```
$(".box").click(function() {
    $(":first .box-data").css("display", "block");
    //$(this).find(":first .box-data").css("display", "block");
});
```

The `box-data` is not visible by default, however by the above code both of them will be visible, unfortunately!

P.S. `display: none;` has been defined in `box-data` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`nextAll(".box-data")`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/):

```
$(".box").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".box-data").first().css("display", "block");
});
```

`nextAll` returns the following siblings *in order*, and `first` chooses just the first of them (`first` = `eq(0)`).